# How to get range of created object 'cells'?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm setting up a 26x26 spreadsheet program in Visual Studio. I have created an object `cell` which inherits textbox but includes also a property `cellID`. Now I have created a `selectedRange` textbox which allows the user to type in a range (example: 'A1:A9') onto which a formula will be executed (example: Sum). I want to grab the typed in range and find a way to use it arithmetically.

I thought maybe I could use the `Split()` method with a `':'` and `','` delimiter but I don't know how to construct this to be usable in my code.

Screenshot of the program:

[image]

```cs
private void btn_sum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0; 

    string[] cells = txt_selectedRange.Text.Split(':',',');
}
```

Comment: are all of those separate `TextBox`es? I recommend looking into the `DataGridView` control

Comment: Yes they are placed in a 2d array of type cell. Cell[,] cell = new Cell[27,27];

Comment: then you can just convert the `A1` notation to row and column indexes to use in nested for loops

Comment: Do you want to get all the cell names from the range? For example, parse "A1:A9" to "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9"? It would be helpful if you gave an example of the result you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel you can have complex range string like this: "D6:F11,I6:I9,J14,N10,P5:Q9", so first you need to split by "," and then for each sub-string containing a ":" you need to get the sub-range of cells.

Hear is a method that gets a range string, parses it and returns a list of cell strings:

```cs
private static List<string> GetCellStrings(string cellRange)
{
    // Cell string to return from this method.
    List<string> cells = new List<string>();

    // Remove whitespace.
    cellRange = cellRange.Replace(" ", "").Trim();

    // First split by ',' to get subranges
    string[] subranges = cellRange.Split(',');

    // Iterate over subranges
    for (int i = 0; i < subranges.Length; i++)
    {
        string range = subranges[i];

        // If the subrange contains a ':', calculate all range cells
        if (range.Contains(':'))
        {
            string[] rangeBounds = range.Split(':');
            char lowerBoundLetter = rangeBounds[0][0];
            char upperBoundLetter = rangeBounds[1][0];
            int lowerBoundNumber = int.Parse(rangeBounds[0].Substring(1));
            int upperBoundNumber = int.Parse(rangeBounds[1].Substring(1));

            for (char columnLetter = lowerBoundLetter; columnLetter <= upperBoundLetter; columnLetter++)
            {
                for (int rowNumber = lowerBoundNumber; rowNumber <= upperBoundNumber; rowNumber++)
                {
                    string cell = columnLetter.ToString() + rowNumber.ToString();
                    cells.Add(cell);
                }
            }
        }
        // If the subrange does not contain a ':', it's a single cell, add it to the list of cells
        else
        {
            cells.Add(range);
        }
    }

    return cells;
}
```

**Note:** This code works only for 26 columns - A to Z.

Example:

```cs
string cellRange = "D6:F11,I6:I9,J14,N10,P5:Q9";

List<string> cells = GetCellStrings(cellRange);

for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cells[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
D6
D7
D8
D9
D10
D11
E6
E7
E8
E9
E10
E11
F6
F7
F8
F9
F10
F11
I6
I7
I8
I9
J14
N10
P5
P6
P7
P8
P9
Q5
Q6
Q7
Q8
Q9
```

Comment: Hi Eliahu, thank you for your response. The idea of using a list was genius and it worked like a charm. I am now able to grab the user's desired range and carry out the methods I have created such as Sum, Mean, Mode and Median. Thanks once more!

Comment: Eliahu. Any chance you could explain what is going on with the initialization of the lowerBoundLetter and upperBoundLetter? What is the use of the second set of square brackets and how does it convert a string value to a char?

Comment: The first set of square brackets gets a `string`, the second set of square brackets gets a `char` from the `string`. Indexing a `string` variable returns a `char` at the index position.